# Is it possible to make Nose only run tests which are sub-classes of TestCase or TestSuite (like unittest.main())

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

My test framework is currently based on a test-runner utility which itself is derived from the Eclipse pydev python test-runner. I'm switching to use Nose, which has many of the features of my custom test-runner but seems to be better quality code.

My test suite includes a number of abstract test-classes which previously never ran. The standard python testrunner (and my custom one) only ran instances of unittest.TestCase and unittest.TestSuite.

I've noticed that since I switched to Nose it's running just about anything which starts withthe name "test" which is annoying... because the naming convention we used for the test-mixins also looks like a test class to Nose. Previously these never ran as tests because they were not instances of TestCase or TestSuite.

Obviously I could re-name the methods to exclude the word "test" from their names... that would take a while because the test framework is very big and has a lot of inheritance. On the other hand it would be neat if there was a way to make Nose only see TestCases and TestSuites as being runnable... and nothing else.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to play with `-m` option for `nosetests`. From documentation:

> A test class is a class defined in a
>   test module that matches testMatch or
>   is a subclass of unittest.TestCase

`-m` sets that `testMatch`, this way you can disable testing anything starting with *test*.

Another thing is that you can add `__test__ = False` to your test case class declaration, to mark it “not a test”.

Comment: The `__test__ = False` trick is not very useful in the case of a parent class, this would force children classes to explicitly specify `__test__ = True` or it would be ignored, that's a dangerous trick to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a truly abstract test class, you could just inherit the abstract class from object, then inherit in the testcases later.

For example:

```
class AbstractTestcases(object):
    def test_my_function_does_something(self):
        self.assertEquals("bar", self.func())
```

And then use it with:

```
class TestMyFooFunc(AbstractTestcases, unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.func = lambda: "foo"
```

Then `nosetests` will pick up only the testcases in `TestMyFooFunc` and not those in `AbstractTestCases`.

Comment: That's a nice way to avoid problem, but the abstract test is then pretty unreadable in my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nose's --attr argument to specify an attribute posessed by the unittest.TestCase.  For instance, I use:

```
nosetests --attr="assertAlmostEqual"
```

You could get even more careful by using *and* and *or* matching:

```
nosetests -A "assertAlmostEqual or addTest"
```

See [unittest's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) for a full list of methods/attributes, and Nose's [description of the capabilities of the --attr plugin](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html).

Comment: This is not the most beautiful solution, but it definitely works, compared to the other suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One addendum to @nailxx 's answer:

You could set `__test__ = False` in the parent class and then *use a metaclass* (see [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/2443886) with some brilliant explanations) to set it back to True when subclassing.

*(Finally, I found an excuse to use a metaclass!)*

Although `__test__` is a double underscore attribute, we have to explicitly set it to `True`, since not setting it would cause python just to lookup the attribute further up the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) and evaluate it to `False`.

Thus, we need to check at class instantiation whether one of the parent classes has `__test__ = False`. If this is the case and the current class definition has not set `__test__` itself, we shall add `'__test__': True` to the attributes dict.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
class TestWhenSubclassedMeta(type):
    """Metaclass that sets `__test__` back to `True` when subclassed.

    Usage:

        >>> class GenericTestCase(TestCase, metaclass=TestWhenSubclassed):
        ...     __test__ = False
        ...
        ...     def test_something(self):
        ...         self.fail("This test is executed in a subclass, only.")
        ...
        ...
        >>> class SpecificTestCase(GenericTestCase):
        ...     pass

    """

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        ATTR_NAME = '__test__'
        VALUE_TO_RESET = False
        RESET_VALUE = True

        values = [getattr(base, ATTR_NAME) for base in bases
                  if hasattr(base, ATTR_NAME)]

        # only reset if the first attribute is `VALUE_TO_RESET`
        try:
            first_value = values[0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            if first_value == VALUE_TO_RESET and ATTR_NAME not in attrs:
                attrs[ATTR_NAME] = RESET_VALUE

        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
```

One could extend this to some more implicit behaviour like “if the name starts with `Abstract`, set `__test__ = False` automatically”, but I for myself would keep the explicit assignment for clarity.

---

Let me paste simple unittests to demonstrate the behavior – and as a reminder that everybody should take the two minutes to test their code after introducing a feature.

```
from unittest import TestCase

from .base import TestWhenSubclassedMeta


class SubclassesTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_subclass_resetted(self):
        class Base(metaclass=TestWhenSubclassedMeta):
            __test__ = False

        class C(Base):
            pass

        self.assertTrue(C.__test__)
        self.assertIn('__test__', C.__dict__)

    def test_subclass_not_resetted(self):
        class Base(metaclass=TestWhenSubclassedMeta):
            __test__ = True

        class C(Base):
            pass

        self.assertTrue(C.__test__)
        self.assertNotIn('__test__', C.__dict__)

    def test_subclass_attr_not_set(self):
        class Base(metaclass=TestWhenSubclassedMeta):
            pass

        class C(Base):
            pass

        with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
            getattr(C, '__test__')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use multiple inheritance on the test case level and let the base class inherit from `object` only. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nose-users/TWgpUUgnLqg/YLx8FD_2U_8J):

```
class MyBase(object):
   def finishsetup(self):
       self.z=self.x+self.y

   def test1(self):
       self.assertEqual(self.z, self.x+self.y)

   def test2(self):
       self.assert_(self.x > self.y)

class RealCase1(MyBase, unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.x=10
       self.y=5
       MyBase.finishsetup(self)

class RealCase2(MyBase, unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.x=42
       self.y=13
       MyBase.finishsetup(self)
```